# Call external API using angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

I am using angular 7. I am new in angular and it is my learning phase. I am going to develop a demo application which will later be enhanced in PWA(progressive web app). Basically, i am going to build a media application which will play videos of different categories like news, sports etc. I get the category data from JSON feed URL which is managed somewhere in server side. Every category have different CDN URL where we can get video URL.

Now, my problem is that when i am trying to get the data from JSON feed URL then it will return CORS policy error and i am unable to fetch data using angular.

I have searched in google but unable to find the solution. Most of the article suggested to allow header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in server side code. But i get the data from different CDN's and i have no access to these CDN's.

How angular access the data from external feed URL?
How to enable Cross Requests in Angular JS?
Should we need to host a middle-ware server and all request will passes via this server where we can allow CORS.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN web docs:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application
>   running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected
>   resources from a server at a different origin. A web application makes
>   a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a
>   different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin.

In short, this means that the browser is blocking cross-origin requests for your angular application. There are methods to circumvent the same-origin policy of the browser (i.e. reverse proxies), but the best approach for your case would be to query these CDN's with your own backend server (i.e. a middleware) and then retrieve the queried data from your own backend server with your angular application.

Answer (score 0):

If the API you're connecting to supports JSONP, you can use that. JSONP is a way of getting around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue, but it has to be supported by the API.

The way it works is that the server returns a response wrapped in a function called parseResponse(…). Then you communicate with the API by creating <script> tags, with the src pointing at the API call. When the script downloads it executes the function, allowing you to grab the data by implementing said function.

Other than that, you can’t. The whole point of cross origin prevention is to stop you from doing this exact thing. Angular nor any other javascript frameworks can help you overcome this limitation.

Your suggestion of using the server for these requests is a potential workaround, but if this is just a proof of concept app then you can simply deactivate the browser’s cross origin policy.

Here’s a chrome extension that does just this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: Is JSONP supports angular 7? if yes then please share code snippet using angular 7.

Comment: It's not Angular that needs to support JSONP, it's the API you're calling.

Comment: Angular supports jsonp through use of the HttpClientJsonpModule. Configure that and then you can fetch with the HttpClient.jsonp method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hacks in angular to overcome the CORS policies. you have to allow your ip from the backend(server). if you want to get media without change in the server you have to find a public apis for fetch media.

Comment: you want say that i have to use middleware(where i need to allow CORS) to bypass the CORS policies?

Comment: nop your api must be allow your ip specifically or it should not restricted by ips(public).

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy for development environment. Just read: https://angular.io/guide/build#using-corporate-proxy

But for production, maybe you will need a proxy server and it will get your requests, use api's of the website you use or just directly proxy to the urls that you want to fetch.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, since you haven't added any code snippet i am just tying to assume your situation.

if you are adding the url directly in the code you have to mark it safe explicitly.

```
<div [src]="www.example.com/id | safe: 'resourceUrl'"></div>
```

and create new pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeHtml,
  SafeStyle,
  SafeScript,
  SafeUrl,
  SafeResourceUrl
} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(
    value: any,
    type: string
  ): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
      case 'html':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
      case 'style':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
      case 'script':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
      case 'url':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
      case 'resourceUrl':
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
      default:
        throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}
```

now you need to import the same in app module in declaration section

```
 declarations: [
...
    SafePipe
...
  ],
```